# Grep Amazon EC2 Free Tier eligible images

Tags: amazon-ec2, grep, amazon-ami

Is there a way to grep images which are "Free Tier Eligible" with ec2-describe-images

Answer (score 3):

All EBS backed AMIs that are under 10 GB are eligible for the free tier.

I guess you can grep to filter out the results of `ec2-describe-images` that are 10 GB or less.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I care only about 64-bit systems.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" "Name=architecture,Values=x86_64" --query 'Images[?BlockDeviceMappings[0].Ebs.VolumeSize<=`10`]'
```

Or a little faster:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" "Name=architecture,Values=x86_64" "Name=block-device-mapping.volume-size,Values=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
```